# Moving Data From Scikit-Learn to Elki for Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I have 100,000 sentences that I've processed into TF-IDF vectors using scikit-learn's `TfidfVectorizer` with highly customized stopwords and nlp stemming. My goal is to cluster the sentences using dbscan or another density-based cluster to discover similar sentences.

In scikit-learn's dbscan implementation, I run out of memory when I cluster more than 40,000 sentences. I have seen suggestions to use ELKI's Java clustering GUI. I'd like to try clustering in Java, but I cannot find a method for moving my TF-IDF vectors from Python to ELKI. ELKI's documentation states that it can handle [sparse vectors](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/HowTo/SparseData) in a particular format or in .arff.

1. Most concrete question. Can anyone suggestion how to move TFIDF vectors from scikit-learn into a format that can be loaded into ELKI.
2. Will ELKI better manage memory than scikit-learn? Or is this pointless work?

Comment: Check out the different parsers for sparse vectors available. There is at least one with one row per document containing `word1 weight1 word2 weight2` per line - trivial to produce. From my experience, ELKI DBSCAN scales very very well with the Cover tree. Increase the Java memory limit - it defaults to 25% of your RAM only!

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me more about Cover tree? I did get the data into ELKI using my own parser, but it is taking much longer to cluster than with scikit. BUT ELKI doesn't crash, so improvement!

Comment: You need to add an index using the index option. I recommend the cover tree.